# PHP preg_match_all / Regular Expression Issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string of text that looks like this:

```
2012-02-19-00-00-00+136571235812571+UserABC.log
```

I need to break this into three pieces of data:  the string to the left of the first + (2012-02-19-00-00-00), the string between the two + (136571235812571) and the string to the right of the + (UserABC.log).

I have this code at the moment:

```
preg_match_all('\+(.*?)\+', $text, $match);
```

The issue I'm having is that the code above returns:  +136571235812571+

Is there a way to use the RegEx to give me all three pieces of data (without the + marks) or do I need a different approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically done with `explode()`:

```
explode('+', '2012-02-19-00-00-00+136571235812571+UserABC.log');
// ['2012-02-19-00-00-00', '136571235812571', 'UserABC.log']
```

You can use `list()` to assign them directly into variables:

```
list($date, $ts, $name) = explode('+', '2012-02-19-00-00-00+136571235812571+UserABC.log');
```

See also: [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) [`list()`](http://php.net/list)

Answer (score 1):

Using [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$str = '2012-02-19-00-00-00+136571235812571+UserABC.log';
$matches = preg_split('/\+/', $str);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012-02-19-00-00-00
    [1] => 136571235812571
    [2] => UserABC.log
)
```

---

Using [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$str = '2012-02-19-00-00-00+136571235812571+UserABC.log';
preg_match_all('/[^\+]+/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done "faster" without using RegEx, if you wanted to get into micro optimization.   Obviously this depends on the context you are writing the code for.

```
$string = "2012-02-19-00-00-00+136571235812571+UserABC.log";
$firstPlusPos = strpos($string, "+");
$secondPlusPos = strpos($string, "+", $firstPlusPos + 1);
$part1 = substr($string, 0, $firstPlusPos);
$part2 = substr($string, $firstPlusPos + 1, $secondPlusPos - $firstPlusPos - 1);
$part3 = substr($string, $secondPlusPos + 1);
```

This code takes 0.003, compared to 0.007 for RegEx on my computer, but of course this will vary depending on hardware.

Comment: Nice solution, but i'd rather go with a short and clean code (explode), +1 thought :)